# How to convert child nodes of a root XML node to json?

Tags: java, xml, json

I have a file with following format

```
<reports>
  <report>
   <text>....</text>
   <author>...</author>
  </report>
  <report>
   <text>....</text>
   <author>...</author>
  </report>
</reports>
```

The reports root node contains several `report` nodes. I want to convert all the individual report nodes into json objects (which I will save as individual files).

I am new to XML and tried using the following code

```
    List<String> readLines = IOUtils.readLines(new FileInputStream(new File("file.xml")));
    String out = String.join("\n", readLines);

    //convert to XML
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    try {
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(out)));
        if (doc != null) {
            XPathExpression expression = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().compile("/reports");
            Node reportsRoot = (Node) expression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODE);
            NodeList reports = reportsRoot.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < reports.getLength(); i++) {
               //I am stuck here. How can I convert the report node into a json object?
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Accessing the XML or creating the JSON? Have you tried JSONObject from http://www.json.org/java/index.html to create the json representation, or any other library?

Comment: Break up the problem into two parts. Figure how to create JSON without worrying about the XML part. Then figure out how to join the two together.

Comment: I have code that can convert XML file to JSON. However, what I have in this case (inside for loop) is a node object `reports.item(i)`. I do not know how to convert node object to json. Each node object represents one report.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to extract XML children and convert them to JSON. So I converted the whole XML file to JSON and then extracted individual reports. That was easier. Here is the code I used:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            List<String> readLines = IOUtils.readLines(new FileInputStream(new File("test.xml")));
            String out = String.join("\n", readLines);
            JSONObject jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(out);

            JSONObject reportsObj = (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("reports");
            JSONArray reports = (JSONArray) reportsObj.get("report");
            int reportCount = reports.length();

            for (int i = 0; i < reportCount; i++) {
                JSONObject report = (JSONObject) reports.get(i);
                System.out.println(report);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```